# Does the crew conduct any actual exploration of Atlantis?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

I just started watching *Stargate Atlantis* series (I am on episode 10 of the first season) and while I like each episode I do not understand why they are not exploring the city itself. Atlantis was the whole point of their journey and now all I can see is them travelling here and there without actually studying the city. I mean... that is THE Atlantis! I cannot stress this enough - THE Atlantis.

So the question is - is there going to be more exploration in future episodes or should I expect just more of those exploration missions via the stargate?

Comment: I **definitely recall them exploring the city**, though I don't remember any episodes exclusively devoted to such. But I haven't finished the series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there will be more exploration episodes, or at least ones containing events resulting from exploration.

These include, but are not limited to (spoiler alert!):

> The discoveries of various labs, including a secret lab - unknown even to the original inhabitants. There's also a virus outbreak, ascension machine, additional jumper bay, underwater drilling platform (near Atlantis), and others.

So there'll definitely be more Atlantis-oriented episodes.

Comment: Couldn't resist looking into the spoiler and now I am waiting eagerly for those episodes :) Thanks!

Comment: Oddly enough, the sets look surprisingly like the rest of Atlantis.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there will be *some* exploration of the city. The reason they aren't exploring yet is due to lack of power. They first search for a new power supply before opening up new areas of the city.

I will warn you, there isn't much city exploring and not many (if any) focused purely on it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the main reason (I somewhat overlooked the fact that they are still searching for that power supply for atlantis). Although it is a bit sad that there is not much focus on the city exploration as this was one of the reasons I started watching this searies in the first place.

Comment: Yeah I know what you're saying. To be honest, the off-world (off-city?) stuff is more interesting in my opinion. The city is pretty much just a super high tech city that does everything people need it to. (With some exception obviously)

Comment: Maybe you are right and pure city exploration would get old after a while. I guess that after watching the first episode I hoped that at least the majority of the first season would be about the atlantis itself, its history and the high tech/weird things they encounter (or anything with "atlantis" setting). It was a bit disappointing to start watching a series called "Atlantis" and end up with another version of star trek :) (even if it is well made).

Comment: Don't dismiss it so quickly, the off-world exploration does lead them to learn a LOT about the Atlantians and about the city etc.

Comment: I am already hooked and beyond the point of no return with this series, so dismissing is not an option :).